# Alfresco with LDAP doesn't show user email addresses

Tags: email, ldap, alfresco

I have an Alfresco 5.0b instance with LDAP authentication configured. The authentication works fine, users can log in and use Alfresco, but their email values doesn't show up in Alfresco even if it's present in LDAP. The LDAP server stores the email values in the `mail` attribute.

The `ldap-authentication.properties` file looks like this:

```
ldap.authentication.active=true
ldap.authentication.allowGuestLogin=false
ldap.authentication.userNameFormat=
ldap.authentication.java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
ldap.authentication.java.naming.provider.url=ldap://127.0.0.1:389
ldap.authentication.java.naming.security.authentication=simple
ldap.authentication.escapeCommasInBind=false
ldap.authentication.escapeCommasInUid=false
ldap.authentication.defaultAdministratorUserNames=
ldap.synchronization.active=false
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.authentication=simple
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.principal=cn\=admin,dc\=ldap,dc\=local
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.credentials=Password
ldap.synchronization.queryBatchSize=0
ldap.synchronization.attributeBatchSize=0
ldap.synchronization.groupQuery=(objectclass\=posixGroup)
ldap.synchronization.groupDifferentialQuery=(&(objectClass\=posixGroup)(!(modifyTimestamp<\={0})))
ldap.synchronization.personQuery=(&(objectclass\=inetOrgPerson)(memberOf=cn\=alfresco-users,ou\=groups,dc\=ldap,dc\=local))
ldap.synchronization.personDifferentialQuery=(&(objectclass\=inetOrgPerson)(!(modifyTimestamp<\={0})))
ldap.synchronization.groupSearchBase=ou\=groups,dc\=ldap,dc\=local
ldap.synchronization.userSearchBase=ou\=people,dc\=ldap,dc\=local
ldap.synchronization.modifyTimestampAttributeName=modifyTimestamp
ldap.synchronization.timestampFormat=yyyyMMddHHmmss'Z'
ldap.synchronization.userIdAttributeName=uid
ldap.synchronization.userFirstNameAttributeName=givenName
ldap.synchronization.userLastNameAttributeName=sn
ldap.synchronization.userEmailAttributeName=mail
ldap.synchronization.userOrganizationalIdAttributeName=o
ldap.synchronization.defaultHomeFolderProvider=largeHomeFolderProvider
ldap.synchronization.groupIdAttributeName=cn
ldap.synchronization.groupDisplayNameAttributeName=description
ldap.synchronization.groupType=posixGroup
ldap.synchronization.personType=inetOrgPerson
ldap.synchronization.groupMemberAttributeName=memberUid
ldap.synchronization.enableProgressEstimation=true
ldap.authentication.java.naming.read.timeout=0
```

The `userEmailAttributeName` is set to `mail`, but it seems to be ineffective. How can be this fixed to have the email values present in Alfresco?

Comment: What happens if you set `ldap.synchronization.active` to true? Normally you want both active

Comment: This seemed to help, thank you!

Comment: did this work ? I am trying to login with email and thus made the following changes##################################ldap.authentication.userNameFormat=mail=%s ###############################
ldap.synchronization.userIdAttributeName=mail , it showed in the user search as email showing as user name but does not let me login